# Caching HTTP responses between browser sessions in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

In [AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#caching) you could simply use

```
$http.get(url, { cache: true}).success(...);
```

for caching between browser sessions.

Is there any example of how to achieve caching of HTTP responses between browser sessions in [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/http#caching)?

Comment: In the second link you provided actually there is an example, the one with the `CachingInterceptor`. Do you need any extra info?

Comment: @leopal, so you mean that you would use an interceptor and store the response in a local storage? I think my question also concerns the scope of the cache - whether you can close the browser in between or not.

Comment: Why you dont want to use Browser cache?

Comment: https://nrempel.com/guides/angular-httpclient-httpinterceptor-cache-requests/ seems like a good example/starting point

Comment: @PetrAveryanov, how would I use the Browser cache? I would like to use that one.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo, `private cache = new Map<string, [Date, HttpResponse<any>]>();` was used in the example you linked. And if I would like it to persist between browser restart, I would use localStorage I guess? I think my confusion around this, is that it is pretty advanced and not a simple switch as in AngularJS.

Comment: Browser decides which requests to cache based on Http headers: Cache-Control, Pragma, Expires. This a 100% backend responsibility and is not connected to angularjs in any way. Usually browser caches images and lots other stuff. In general there should be some specific reasons to use something else for caching.

Comment: The example implementation is in-memory, so it wont archive what you are looking for.  You could use something like `ngx-cookie` or directly the local storage API in order to persist your cache across different instances of your app.